# How to get a seamless transition from app bar to status bar

Tags: android, material-components-android

So I'm currently trying to migrate an app to use Material 3 consistently. Previously it was stiched together without any real design concept. Now I want to actually look like something to take serious.

One thing I haven't been able to figure out is how to give the status bar the same color as the title bar. Currently it looks like this:

[image: Screenshot of problem]

The official documentation however lists the seamless version in the ["What's new" section](https://m3.material.io/components/top-app-bar/overview):

[image: Example]

I'm currently using a `LinearLayout` with the `Theme.Material3.DayNight` theme (without any modifications for now) and from what I was able to learn from the documentation I need to make use of components like `MaterialToolbar` inside a `AppBarLayout` inside a `CoordinatorLayout` so everything works as intended. I tried doing that and the scrolling and lifting now works as described in the documentation, but the color of the status bar remains unchanged unfortunately.

I'm not sure at this point if my expectations are wrong or if my code is. I believe that there has to be a built-in mechanism that automatically adjusts the status bar's colour to dynamically match the one of the app bar. I might be wrong though and the material-components-android expects me to implement the logic myself. In any case, could someone point me towards an example implementation where this transition is seamless? This way I could modify my code to implement this behaviour.

I'm currently using `com.google.android.material:material:1.5.0` in case this is relevant to the problem.

Thanks in advance!